# mapping w=exp(z)

Tags: complex-analysis

Why all books say that the closed strip $0 \le y \le\pi$ is mapped by the complex function 
$w=\exp(z)$ into the upper half of the complex plane including the real axis? Should $w=0$ be excluded because $\exp(z)$ is never zero?
I would really appreciate anybody's opinion.

Comment: What books say this?

Comment: If the book says _into_, there is no problem with $0$ not being an image of $\exp$. If it said _onto_, that would be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to prove that all books say that, and in fact I doubt so. Anyway if your book is using the extended complex plane and includes (directed) $\infty$ in the strip, then indeed you will get $0$ (and $\infty$ in all directions) in the image.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I see that.

Comment: By the way, I saw the "including the real axis" part and missed the little word "into", so Daniel's comment holds. However it is nice to see that including $\infty$ makes it "onto" the upper half of the extended complex plane.